# I cannot find layout preview tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot find the layout preview tab in Xml file. It is not on the right side of the window. I tried to look "tool windows" in "view" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout files in Android Studio have 2 tabs on the bottom: design and text. You should click design.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in: "View -> Tool Windows -> Preview"?

Why not for you?

Did you have a screenshot of your options?

Comment: it was not there. I created new  another project and problem solved. I don't know why it was'nt  there before.